# Configuration class doesn't run when I add @Autowired WebService field

Tags: java, spring, cxf

I have a setup `Spring` + `Apache CXF` and I'm trying to make `CustomerWebServiceImpl` injectable. To do this I should inject it within `@Autowired WebServiceConfig`. When I do this, the `WebServiceConfig` doesn't even run(checked via debugger). In stack trace I see the following exception:

```
NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.beginnercourse.softcomputer.domains.customer.CustomerWebService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

I've checked spring annotations, everything marked with `@Component`/`@Service`. Made sure that I don't initialize any of these beans with `new`. Tried to replace field autowiring by setters

I have seen that there could be unexpected problems, like [here](http://javaworkbench.blogspot.com/2011/07/spring-apache-cxf-and-autowired.html)

My code:

CustomerWebService

```
@WebService
public interface CustomerWebService {

    String addCustomer(CustomerDto newCustomer);
}
```

CustomerWebServiceImpl

```
@Component
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.soft.domains.customer.CustomerWebService")
public class CustomerWebServiceImpl implements CustomerWebService {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerService customerService;

    @Override
    public String addCustomer(CustomerDto newCustomer) {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
        customerService.create(new CustomerEntity());
        return "Hello " + newCustomer.getName();
    }
}
```

WebServiceConfig

```
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerWebService customerWebService;

    @Bean(name = Bus.DEFAULT_BUS_ID)
    public SpringBus springBus() {
        return new SpringBus();
    }


    @Bean
    public Endpoint endpoint() {
        EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(springBus(), customerWebService);
        endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8080/services/customer");
        return endpoint;
    }
}
```

**UPD:** I seems like only one of my configuration classes(`RootConfig`) is initialized fine. Others are not initializing beans. Maybe WebApplicationInitializer.onStartup expect another configuration. Then what kind of startup should be used to run new CXFServlet() with such Configuration classes?

```
public class WebServiceDispatcherServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    private static final String SERVICE_DISPATCHER_SERVLET = "service_dispatcher_servlet";

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.register(WebServiceConfig.class, RootConfig.class, PersistenceConfig.class);
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new CXFServlet());
        dispatcher.addMapping("/services/*");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your webservice isn't managed by Spring but CXF, despite the `@Component`... If this class isn't in a package that is scanned by Spring the annotation doesn't do anything.

Comment: Make sure that you perform `@ComponentScan` on package where `CustomerWebServiceImpl` is placed

Comment: Thank you. l have updated post after the advice-based investigation.